# remove element from JSON array in AWS dynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I need to remove a single element from json array in aws dynamo db using node.js. I have following table, name :student.

[image]
I need to remove `{name:fr4,id:104}` from dynamodb using partition key email and id=104. is it possible with dynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible. With an UpdateExpression you can delete an element from a set. I think you would need to know the full item you would like to remove, though. So in your case the id:104 might not be enough.

Check the docs at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html => section "UpdateExpression" => Delete

If all else fails you need to read the item or at least the friends atrribute, change it, and write it back

Answer (score 0):

```
aws dynamodb update-item \
    --table-name rulesets \
    --key '{"partition_key_col_name":{"S":"cljr7n7tb0001pn6x30k869vf2"}, "sort_key_col_name":{"S":"cljr7n7tb0001pn6x30k869vf"}}' \
    --update-expression "REMOVE steps[0].conditions.#a" \
    --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#a":"all[1].path"}' \
    --return-values ALL_NEW
```

Updating json collections
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html